# Как сбросить несколько таймеров одновременно?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

Задача в следюущем:
Есть несколько таймеров, которые создаются динамически через цикл. Таймер может быть один, а может быть 10, 15, 20. Нужно реализовать их остановку.

Есть следующий код:

```js
let actions = {
  timer: [],
  start: [],

  stop: function(counter) {
    clearTimeout(actions.timer[counter]);
  }

};

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    actions.start[i] = function timerFunc() {
      actions.timer[i] = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('hi');
        setTimeout(timerFunc,500);
      }, 500);
    }
}
```

Работа довольно простая: в цикле присваиваем actions.start функцию с таймером.
Также есть метод, который тормозит нужный нам таймер - actions.stop

Чтобы проверить, как работает код, вводим в консоль:

```
actions.start[0]()
actions.start[1]()
```

А потом тормозим оба таймера с помощью:

```
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
```

А дальше происходит беда - их получается тормозить иногда сразу, иногда после нескольких попыток. Причем, чем меньше промежуток срабатывания, тем сложнее его затормозить. При 500мс (см. timerFunc), мне понадобилось 4 попытки (копирую результат из консоли):

```
actions.start[0]()
actions.start[1]()
undefined
(10)hi
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
undefined
(4)hi
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
undefined
(2)hi
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
undefined
(2)hi
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
undefined
```

Вопрос в том, почему так происходит и как остановить таймеры, созданные динамично, с первого раза?
Например, **если я очень быстро** введу в консоль:

```
actions.stop(0)
actions.stop(1)
```

То все получается. Если хоть немного промедлю, то таймеры продолжают тикать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  actions.timer[i] = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hi');
    setTimeout(timerFunc,500);
  }, 500);
```

Потому что в момент выполнения первого события таймера для `actions.timer[i]` это значение (`actions.timer[i]`) больше не указывает на таймер, ждущий выполнения, а просто содержит какое-то значение, не соответствующее никакому таймеру. И если вызов `clearTimeout` попадает в промежуток до присвоения нового значения `actions.timer[i]`, то `clearTimeout` ничего не делает.

---

```
actions.start[i] = function() {
  var timerFunction = function() {
    actions.timer[i] = setTimeout(timerFunction, 500);
  }
  actions.timer[i] = timerFunction();
}
```

Comment: Хорошо. И как же решить эту задачу тогда? Как правильно сбрасывать таймер, чтобы четко попадать в момент, когда actions.timer[i] содержит значение, соответствующее таймеру?

Comment: @MichaelFedotov Добавил.

Comment: этот код не работает

Comment: @MichaelFedotov не работает, а что делает? Вы его неаккуратно к себе скопировали :)

Comment: Прошу прощения. Работает. Пожалуйста, объясните более подробно, почему мой код не работал, а ваш работает нормально? Ведь, по сути он выполняет то же самое.

Comment: @MichaelFedotov Подождите. Текст из ответа понятен?

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то когда в консоли ввожу actions.timer, то вижу массив из значений для таймера. Эти значения меняются. В моем случае, я написал код таким образом, что часто попадаю именно в момент смены значений. В вашем случае, actions.stop() срабатывает всегда. Значения все также меняются. Так в чем же магия?

Comment: @MichaelFedotov "Магия" в том, что в Вашем коде присутствует второй `setTimeout`, который создает временнЫе промежутки, в течение которых значения в массиве не соответствуют никаким запущенным таймерам. В моем коде этих "разрывов" нет.